# Driving 7-Segment Displays using a microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, 7segmentdisplay

Before I start out, let me just point out that I'm new to hardware design. In fact, this is just hobby for now, but might turn into something later. Because of this, I don't follow any standards per se, but I like to be as organized and efficient as possible.

I designed a 16-bit microprocessor from the bottom-up, including the architecture and instruction set, as a hobby project. It has been implemented on a Spartan 6 FPGA and is working great. I made a casing for the processor to be used as a panel, which integrates with the DMA capabilities of the design.

One of these is the ability to choose which part of the processor you're currently observing on the data output display. This information about the currently chosen 'entity' is also to be display on a 3-digit 7-segment display, in characters. For example, 'ALU', 'STA' for Stack, 'ADD' for MAR, etc.

This is completely unnecessary, but I'd like to do this anyway, as a visual treat. Since I'm new to circuit design entirely, what I thought of first was to use an array of multiplexers to simply choose the state of the 7-segment displays depending on the input. But this would require some manual IC wiring, which I'm not too keen on doing. I tried to make a PCB, but most of the copper tracks were broken.

What I would like to do is use a microcontroller (something I've never done before) to achieve this. I have never used a microcontroller, and I'm unaware as to which particular one would be useful in the scenario. I'd appreciate it if someone took the time to point me in the right direction.

Ah, and also, the reason I'm not simply using the FPGA to drive these three displays is because I've run out of the 70 GPIOs on the development board.

Comment: You've never used a microcontroller, yet you've designed your own 16-bit microprocessor and implemented it in FPGA?  I don't know if I should question your architecture or the process to which you are learning.  Either way, if you are indeed out of pins and need to get clever, we are going to need to know how fast your custom microprocessor is running at

Comment: Almost any with sufficient pins will do. Map the segments to port bits and create a lookup table in software. Likely you will scan across the digits outputting the segments for each in turn.

Comment: @Funkyguy, this is not hard to imagine if someone has followed a course track focused on computation structures rather than applications... trivial tasks are not covered.  The clock speed of the examined processor doesn't really matter as the human eye can only see so much.

Comment: @ChrisStratton True true, its just oddly different these days for somebody to start with an FPGA over the much more common Arduino or microcontroller.  I'm not too worried about the eye not being able to see it, but if the....oh wait I mis-understood the question.  You're right.  Well OP could certainly use an Arduino for this then, so long as OP can free up a couple of pins.

Comment: @Funkyguy I've not even started undergrad yet. The microprocessor is coded in Verilog, and the architecture fits my purpose. I'm not following a course of any sort. It's just a hobby project.

The processor runs using the clock onboard the development board at 100 MHz, but the display updates only at 20 Hz, which is pretty high in itself. The difference is not perceivable. Since it's a minicomputer with nothing more than a couple 7-Segment displays, it doesn't matter.

Also, I'm aware that an Arduino would work, but I do not have one and would like to learn microcontrollers as well!

Comment: @ShreyasVinod Perfect.  I would recommend getting an Arduino and learning microcontrollers with it.  There are many tutorials all over the internet.  I'll recommend caution though; since you've made your own architecture, I don't think you'll have a problem with this.  Since Arduino is so wide-spread, with such a large community, much of the programming is already done for many common applications.  As such, it is easy to be spoiled by that.  So just because you might have to program something from scratch occasionally, don't be put off by that.

Comment: @Funkyguy I'm never put off by coding things from scratch! In fact, I prefer to use my own code. The microprocessor was re-coded three times with three complete architecture changes to finally get it working. 

I would like to try to use old school microcontrollers instead of arduinos though!

Guess I should research more. Thanks for the helpful insight.

Comment: @ShreyasVinod Older controllers would be pretty nifty!  Personally I would suggest starting with a more modern controller just to learn the ropes of microcontrollers, then move to 8051.

Comment: Almost every vendor makes something that would fit this need, you might as well shop by what development tools or programmers fit your budget, host O/S or your working philosophy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of which way you choose to go, you're going to have to share some of those 70 "used-up" I/Os with whatever you're going to use to drive the displays, so I suggest you use four of them, [I/Os] go the simple hardware route, and use a couple of TI 16 channel [LED drivers](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc5926-q1.pdf) for just long enough to update your displays periodically.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's a possibility.  But it really only takes one signal, as the FPGA could output an asynchronous serial message easily received by a microcontroller.

Comment: But to what end?  You've still got to drive 21 segments, and if all you're doing is interposing an MCU to reduce The I/O load sharing on the FPGA from 4 to 1, it hardly seems worth it, IMO. Ah, but wait... It's just a hobby project, so for the sake of learning it's probably a valid exercise even though The OP'll eventually have to / want to come to grips with hardware. ;)

Comment: @EMFields I believe this is for serial transfer from the FPGA to the chip for output? I apologize if my question wasn't clear enough. The data to be displayed on the three displays is the same all the time, but needs to be multiplexed between 8 possible states. Something like a lookup table would work. It woud be impractical to keep sending the same data over and over. The 3-bit input that chooses the state isn't actually internal to the FPGA, but external (the same signal is passed on to the FPGA as well).

Comment: Might be a silly question in my opinion, but I just want to dump the multiplexing onto a microcontroller so that I do not have to manually wire up 21 8-bit data selectors to each and every segment. Plus, I could change what the multiplexing would output, if I use a microcontroller, instead of being not able to change it in the former case since it has already been hardcoded.

Am I right?

Comment: @Shreyas: Re. your first comment; using the shift register approach, the data is sent from the source to the 5926 as a 21 bit serial data stream which is clocked into the chip and then latched in the 5926's parallel output register where it drives all 21 LED segments statically, as a constant-current sink, until the next update.

Comment: @Shreyas: Re. your second comment: You only have to connect one wire per segment to the 5926's output latch, and you can change the display reading anytime you want to merely by changing the bit sequence of the serial input to the 5926 and then latching that 'word' into the 5926's output register.  So, there's really nothing hard coded, since the 5926 will light up whatever segments you tell it to.

Comment: @EMFields Never tried to do serial though. Might be the best time to do! To be perfectly honest with you, the only reason the FPGA's 70 pins have been used is because all outputs and inputs are parallel. The data output takes up 21 outputs (20 outputs for 5 7-segments [BCD] and 1 extra bit for sign) and the current address output takes up another 16. I might just dump the 4511 and use this entirely!

Comment: Much more flexibility. Saves around what, 25 pins and offers me the customizability of displaying anything I want on the display, rather than having to be constrained by what the 4511 can.

Comment: @EMFields Success! Worked out quite well. Got a serial interface running at 500 kHz and probably can go even faster. Absolutely no LED blinking at all! I went with the 4094 though, an 8-bit latched shift register. It's a little dim though, probably because the IC isn't designed to drive LEDs. I might perhaps add transistors. Oh well, first tries are not always the best.